# How do you incorporated MathJax into a GitHub Pages site?

Tags: github-pages, mathjax

## How do you incorporate MathJax into a GitHub Pages Site?

People have asked this question here multiple times but they’re old. So I’m trying to figure out how to incorporate *MathJax 3* into a GitHub Pages site.

### I have looked into this problem...

After going over this guide

https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll

how do I then incorporate *Mathjax 3* into my site?

### Edit

I have this in my `_includes/head.html`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-svg.js">
</script>
```

And in my `_config.yml` I have;

```
    math_engine: mathjax
```

And in my post I wrote:

```
   usemath: true
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried and where did you run into a problem? There's really nothing special you have to do -- add [a script loading MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/start.html) to an appropriate jekyll layout, add [TeX content the way kramdown likes](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/math_engine/mathjax.html) and you're done - [demo](https://pkra.github.io/jekyll-now//Hello-World/).

Comment: I have added the mathjax script to head.html in my _includes folder. But it’s not working.

Comment: I'm afraid without seeing what you've tried, it's hard to help. You can see the [last commits](https://github.com/pkra/jekyll-now/commits/master) for the link I shared to see what's necessary. Otherwise, you'll need to share more information.

Comment: @Peter I have edited my post and wrote down what I have in my repo.

Comment: That looks about right. Without seeing the code, there's not much more to say.